# Recreate Netsuite Custom Records using XML

Tags: netsuite

Is there a way I can export the XML metadata for custom records I have created in a sandbox and create them in another environment?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. NetSuite provides the SuiteCloud Development Framework (SDF) for exactly this purpose. Both the Eclipse and WebStorm official plugins provide SDF functionality, and there is a CLI you can download as well.

Search the Help docs for "SuiteCloud Development Framework" and get started.